# How to know if a Basic Block PostDominate another one?

Tags: clang, llvm

I'm trying to write an analysis and one of the features that I need is to know if a node PostDominate another.

I already know that I have to use:

```
void LazyProfitability::getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {
   AU.addRequired<PostDominatorTreeWrapperPas>();
   AU.setPreservesAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a `PostDominatorTree` object from the analysis results:

```cpp
auto PDT = &getAnalysis<PostDominatorTreeWrapperPass>().getPostDomTree();
```

And use it after that in the following manner:

```cpp
// returns true iff A post-dominates B
PDT->dominates(A, B);
```